# Enumerate json and get a specific key for each one iOS Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

i have a json data

```
   "Arfb Kash" =     {
        g = 9q9hrh1bbv;
        location =         (
            "37.3317034",
            "-122.0336955"
        );
        title = "Arfb Kash";
    };
    "Aryan Kashyap" =     {
        g = 9q9hrh5sdd;
        location =         (
            "37.33233141",
            "-122.0312186"
        );
        title = "Aryan Kashyap";
    };
    Park =     {
        g = 9q9hrh44su;
        location =         (
            "37.3319949",
            "-122.0331756"
        );
    };
}
```

i want to enumerate through this data and get the title string for every parameter i am using iOS Objective c and help how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using fast enumeration.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = /* your dictionary from the question */;
NSMutableArray *titles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *key in dictionary) {
    NSDictionary *subDictionary = dictionary[key];
    NSString *title = subDictionary[@"title"];
    if (title) {
        [titles addObject:title];
    }
}
```